# What is "Last Activity" mean in docusign reports

Tags: spring, docusignapi

In Envelope reports of "docuSign" what is last activity means.Is it something that user click on the docusign form or something else I am not getting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any activity related to your envelope is tracked, recorded and presented to you in the certificate of completion (and the history view for the envelopes).
Activities include:

1. Signing an envelope.
2. Voiding an envelope.
3. Viewing an envelope.
4. Re-assigning an envelope to someone else.
5. Declining to Sign.
6. Checking signer location.
7. Correcting an envelope.
8. Reminder is sent.
9. Envelope expired.

this is just a partial list.
Hope this helps.